# why invoking a service in my servlet gives me an NPE (spring)

Tags: spring, servlets

I have defined a service in Spring

```
@Service("StockageService")
public class StockageServiceImpl implements StockageService{
}
```

with

```
public interface StockageService extends Serializable {
```

}

And I need in a servlet to invoke this service

So I wrote

```
public class SpringApplicationContextListener implements ServletContextListener {
    @Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    ApplicationContext ac = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");

    sce.getServletContext().setAttribute("applicationContext", ac);            
}

public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}
```

}

And

```
public class handler extends HttpServlet  {

 private String message;

 private  StockageService  stockageService;

@Override
public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
   super.init(config);

   ApplicationContext ac = (ApplicationContext) config.getServletContext().getAttribute("applicationContext");

 this.stockageService = (StockageService)ac.getBean("StockageService");
```

}

The problem is that I get a NPE at the last mentionned line

```
    (StockageService)ac.getBean("StockageService");
```

Where could I have made a mistake ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, thanks ankur-singhal for having taken the time to answer my question

I understand the reasonnement of your answer but it does not work when I invoke

```
ApplicationContextUtils. getApplicationContext().getBean("StockageService");
```

So I used a trick which works but I do not understand very well

I override the init in my servlet as it follows

```
@Override
public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
super.init(config);

SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnServletContext(this,
  config.getServletContext());
```

}

and I have to put a

```
 @Autowired
 private  StockageService  stockageService;
```

in the servlet and it works

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `ApplicationContext` itself is comming as `null`.

Look at below code and try make use of this.

`ApplicationContextUtils.java`

We will create the following utility class, it implements `ApplicationContextAware` and provides the `setApplicationContext` which will be invoked by spring container and the `applicationContext` will be passed by it. We store it in a static variable and expose it through a get method so that it can be accessed all through the application.

You can set the same while creating `ApplicationContext`

```
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;

public class ApplicationContextUtils implements ApplicationContextAware {

  private static ApplicationContext ctx;

  @Override
  public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext appContext)
      throws BeansException {
    ctx = appContext;

  }

  public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
    return ctx;
  }
}
```